# Delta function of form: $\frac 1 {4π} \nabla ^2 \frac 1 {\lvert r - {r'} \rvert}$

Tags: dirac-delta, laplacian

I was looking at a wikipedia article and saw the following expression given for a delta function in three dimensions:
$$\delta (r-r') = \frac 1 {4π} \nabla ^2 \frac 1 {\lvert r -{r'}\rvert}$$
I was hoping someone could show me how this is derived. Intuitively, I thought that the 4π comes about from using the divergence theorem to convert a volume integral over all space into a surface integral, where 4π would be the total solid angle.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to check that $\frac 1 {4π}\nabla ^2 \frac 1 {\lvert r -{r'}\rvert}$ is zero for $r\neq r'$. All you need to show that it integrates to $1$ on a any volume containing $r=r'.$ For any such volume carve out a small sphere of radius $\varepsilon$ around $r'.$ The integral in the rest of the volume is zero, and the integral on that sphere is given by\begin{align}
\frac 1 {4π} \int_{B^3(r',\varepsilon)}\nabla ^2 \frac 1 {\lvert r -{r'}\rvert}dV &= \frac 1 {4π} \int_{\partial B^3(r',\varepsilon)}\nabla  \frac 1 {\lvert r -{r'}\rvert}\cdot d\vec A\\
&= \frac 1 {4π} \int_{S^2(r',\varepsilon)}  \frac {-1}  {\varepsilon^2} dA\\
&= \frac 1 {4π\varepsilon^2} \int_{S^2(r',\varepsilon)}  dA = 1\\
\end{align}
where I have used divergence theorem in the first line.